# Join and Replace between two date in a calendar SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to created a calendar that give you the parameters between 20ths month to 20ths of the next month, with the exception of april 19/04/2021, where I want to splite it in two parts (as you can see in the first two code lines).

The problem that I have is that when I want to join everything I have an extra 19/04/2021 with the regular parameter. Someone knows how can I delate that only row (4th row)?

I want to delate this row

[image]

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f11f09035757a081ed540c85fc908bc8

```
SELECT  '19/04/2021' as mes, '2021-03-20T00:00:00.000' as inicio_mes, '2021-03-31T23:59:59.000' as fin_mes UNION
SELECT  '19/04/2021' as mes, '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000' as inicio_mes, '2021-04-19T23:59:59.000' as fin_mes UNION
SELECT
*
    FROM (
    
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(SECOND,-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(MONTH, 1, fecha),120)),103) AS mes,

        CONVERT(DATETIME, fecha, 120) AS inicio_mes,

        DATEADD(SECOND,-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(MONTH, 1, fecha),120)) AS fin_mes

            FROM (
            
                SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20200120', GETDATE()) + 1)

                fecha = DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.OBJECT_ID) - 1, '20200120')

                FROM 

                    SYS.ALL_OBJECTS a CROSS JOIN SYS.ALL_OBJECTS b
                    ) td
            ) ta
            
ORDER BY inicio_mes DESC
```

Any help is really appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: Of course you have 2 rows for `2021-04-19`; you define those 2 rows at the very start of your `UNION`. The first columns for the 2 `SELECT` statements both have `'19/04/2021' as mes` as their definition.

Comment: Yes, I have three rows with date 2021-04-19, the ones that I write a part and the one that I dont want is the one that I get for default in the calendar `19/04/2021 2021-03-20 00:00:00.000 2021-04-19 23:59:59.000` . I hope I have been clearer with the explanation

Comment: If you don't want the row for `2021-04-19` from the calendar table, why not use a `WHERE` to exclude it?

Comment: Add to the `WHERE` clause in the last query `WHERE mes <> '19/04/2021'`

Comment: Thank you @Squirrel, sorry for the foolish question xD,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXCEPT` operator to eliminate that particular record.

```
SELECT  '19/04/2021' as mes, '2021-03-20T00:00:00.000' as inicio_mes, '2021-03-31T23:59:59.000' as fin_mes UNION
SELECT  '19/04/2021' as mes, '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000' as inicio_mes, '2021-04-19T23:59:59.000' as fin_mes UNION
SELECT
*
    FROM (
    
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(SECOND,-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(MONTH, 1, fecha),120)),103) AS mes,

        CONVERT(DATETIME, fecha, 120) AS inicio_mes,

        DATEADD(SECOND,-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(MONTH, 1, fecha),120)) AS fin_mes

            FROM (
            
                SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20200120', GETDATE()) + 1)

                fecha = DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.OBJECT_ID) - 1, '20200120')

                FROM 

                    SYS.ALL_OBJECTS a CROSS JOIN SYS.ALL_OBJECTS b
                    ) td
            ) ta
            
EXCEPT
SELECT '19/04/2021' as mes,'2021-03-20 00:00:00.000' as inicio_mes, '2021-04-19 23:59:59.000' as fin_mes
       
ORDER BY inicio_mes DESC
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9d105e094862783c11efa185242d54bb)